# How would I run C# code that accesses an obfuscated program within that program?

Tags: c#, obfuscation

**Background:**
I have a program that is obfuscated. I also have a button that I can click that will load a C# file as a script, then compile and run the code. I am linking in all of the DLLs and the main EXE when I compile the C# script so that the code can access all the elements of my running program.

This all works fine when running in a non-obfuscated version of my program. The issue is that after I obfuscate the program all the type and function names get obfuscated and I can no longer run the C# script code that accesses these types.

**Question:**
How would I allow my script code to run in the obfuscated program? Is there a way to obfuscate the script on the fly or have the script be able to access the obfuscated objects?

I tried using `var` and `object` to pass classes to the script, but I cannot use `var` in argument lists and I have to cast an `object` to the correct type (which is obfuscated) to use it.

I also cannot use `dynamic` because it, too, attempts to call each function as the non-obfuscated function name. For instance, if I do the following:

```
dynamic o = myObfuscatedObject;
o.MyObfuscatedFunction();
```

The actual function name is some scrambled name, not `MyObfuscatedFunction`, so it will error out.

I'm out of ideas at the moment. Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Update:**
In response to the comments given:

- I have no way, currently, to obfuscate my script code with the same obfuscation map as the referenced assemblies.
- It seems that all types and functions, both public and private, all get obfuscated **except** for those referenced by other assemblies within my solution, which makes sense. If a function or type is not being referenced outside of the current assembly the name is not needed elsewhere and therefore gets obfuscated.
- Interfaces also seem to be obfuscated using the above rule.

Comment: You can't do that. Your only option is to obfuscate the dynamic code using the same obfuscation map as the referenced assemblies, so that the class and member names become the same.

Comment: Can't your rely on an interface declaration so you won't need the `dynamic`?

Comment: Typically public Types and Functions should not be obfuscated.  If they are your obfuscator is broken.

Comment: @MikeWebb: any thoughts on the comments of Yaur and others?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Just updated my question with responses.

Comment: Which obfuscator are you using? There should be a possibility to avoid serialization of all publics (else they won't work with Office add-ins for example).

Comment: It doesn't make sense that functions not referenced outside of your assembly are obfuscated. That is what the internal access modifier is for. If something is public it is meant to be used by the outside world. Your obfuscator is either poorly designed or misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

If you're obfuscating public members then you're breaking your API; it's not going to be easy (if at all possible) to work around that if you're going to then try to consume the original public API.

If you have no way around your requirements then I suspect you need to change your obfuscation settings to *not* obfuscate names of public members. Generally speaking this is the more sensible setting anyway (because if it's not going to be used by a third party, why is it public at all?).